# From Logic App how to make a call to privately hosted SOAP based Web Service on some on-premise Server

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-relay

We have a Logic App and  private SOAP based Web Service hosted on some on-premise network.

Based on some parameters, we need to call this Web Service from the Log App.

**What are the possible and secure ways to implement this ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have your Azure Relay to implement this. It didn't require me to make any changes on the on premises firewalls settings

Answer (score 2):

The best way achieve your ask by creating a custom Logic App Connector using the On Prem Data Gateway.

- Install the gateway as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install)
- Create Custom Logic App Connector as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/connectors/custom-connectors/)

  - Login to your Azure subscription where you have on-premise data gateway registered.
  - Create a resource of type “Logic Apps Custom Connector”.
  - Open a custom connector and click on edit. Choose API Endpoint as SOAP and Call mode as SOAP to REST and then browse to upload WSDL file of your on-premise webservice.
  - Don’t forget to select “Connect via on premise data gateway”

Refer [this blog](https://www.codit.eu/blog/connecting-to-on-premise-http-endpoints-from-logic-app/) for more details.

Comment: I am looking for solution from Relay service perspective. Do you have any suggestions on it?